# Issue installing packages on Solaris

Tags: solaris, sunray

I am trying to setup a utility that requires several packages. However, when I attempt to install the packages, the install fails with the message `Unable to parse repository response` - what do I need to do to rectify this?

```
root@SRSS1:~# /opt/SUNWut/sbin/utadm -L on
Error: SUNWdhcsb SUNWdhcs SUNWdhcm packages are not installed.  These are the Binary
        File Format data modules used to store the DHCP data.  These
        packages are required for Sun Ray interface configuration.
root@SRSS1:~# pkg install SUNWdhcsb
pkg: 0/1 catalogs successfully updated:

Unable to contact valid package repository: http://pkg.oracle.com/solaris/release
Encountered the following error(s):
Unable to parse repository response
root@SRSS1:~# uname -a
SunOS SRSS1 5.11 snv_151a i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
```

Comment: PEBCAK - firewall was blocking it.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

This problem was caused by a firewall blocking access to the repository.